# Coding Language for creating App on Salesforce AppExchange

Tags: appexchange, python

I know the coding languages Salesforce primarily uses are Apex and Javascript. I'm interested in creating a Salesforce App on Salesforce AppExchange. Is it possible to create said app using Python?

Comment: I'll leave this one to someone who has experience with creating AppExchange packages, but I highly suspect the answer is no (unless you do some work/processing on your own web-facing server(s) in which case you can use any language you want). On platform code = Apex, period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to create a Python App on the Salesforce App Exchange. It is a marketplace for applications/components which can be installed into Salesforce orgs, whereas Python applications cannot be. Looking through the "Solution Types", the available options are Apps, Bolt Solutions, Flow Solutions, Lightning Data, and Components. Of those, only the first option could even conceivably contain Python, but here App is strictly defined as a package (either managed or unmanaged), which becomes more obvious when you look at the filtering options for Clouds and Features. None of the available options would support Python.